# Service Fabric - "object is closed" exception via ActorProxy

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

I'm catching the following exception on my cluster, randomly when an actor calls another one via ActorProxy:

**System.Fabric.FabricObjectClosedException: The object is closed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80071BFE
   at System.Fabric.Interop.NativeRuntime.IFabricKeyValueStoreReplica6.CreateTransaction()
   at System.Fabric.KeyValueStoreReplica.CreateTransactionHelper(KeyValueStoreTransactionSettings settings)
   at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.WrapNativeSyncInvoke[TResult](Func`1 func, String functionTag, String functionArgs)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.WrapNativeSyncInvoke[TResult](Func`1 func, String functionTag, String functionArgs)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Runtime.KvsActorStateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass14.b__13()
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Runtime.ActorStateProviderHelper.d__6`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Runtime.ActorStateManager.<ContainsStateAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at PosteItaliane.Sin.StateManagement.ObservableState.SingleValueWrapper`1.d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Users\maurosag\Source\Repos\Equitalia3\SIN\PI.Sin.StateManagement\ObservableState\SingleValueWrapper.cs:line 21
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at PosteItaliane.Sin.Utility.ServiceFabric.StatefulActor`1.get_State() ...**.

Searching on the web, i cannot figure out how to resolve it; the only discussions concern with Powershell exec:

“This means that this replica got demoted from primary to secondary. The client will re-resolve and reconnect to the new primary if you let the exception bubble up. The existing processing will drain on the primary. I am resolving the issue as "By Design". Please feel free to reopen if you still have question.”

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's happening at SingleValueWrapper.cs:line 21 where the exception is being thrown? Can you include a code snippet?

Comment: here's the code:        public override async Task<T> GetValueAsync()
        {
            if (await StateManager.ContainsStateAsync(Name)) \\ line 21
            {
                return await StateManager.GetStateAsync<T>(Name);
            }
            else
            {
                var newValue = _newValueConstructor.Invoke();
                await StateManager.SetStateAsync(Name, newValue);
                return newValue;
            }
        }